# Format date in Kendo Template

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, kendo-template

I'm trying to format my `DateTime` object in my Kendo ListView Template but the suggested `kendo.toString` method doesn't seem to work for me.

I've cut out a lot of code that doesn't relate to my problem to make it a little more simple to understand.

I have a `Kendo DataSource` that looks like the following:

```
contactDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/baa/contact/getcontacts",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET"
        }
     },
     schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: true },
                CompanyName: { type: "string" },
                ContactName: { type: "string" },
                ContactPhone: { type: "string" },
                ContactEmail: { type: "string" },
                ImageUrl: { type: "string" },
                Website: { type: "string" },
                RecentBaas: [
                    {
                        Name: { type: "string" },
                        StatusDisplay: { type: "string" },
                        Status: { type: "number" },
                        LastModDate: { type: "date" }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

And then I have a template on my view that looks like the following:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-templ" id="contactTemplate">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            # for (var i = 0; i < RecentBaas.length; i++) { #
            # if (RecentBaas[i].Status == 1) { #
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    <p>#=kendo.toString(RecentBaas[i].LastModDate, "F")#</p>
                </div>
            # } #
            # } #
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I'm not getting any errors in my console when I load this page, but the date is not formatted at all. It still just shows as `/Date(1461203814927)/` for example.

I've read the Kendo Documentation on how to use the `toString` function to format `DateTime` objects and as far as I can tell I'm doing everything right. But maybe I'm still missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-templ" id="contactTemplate">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            # for (var i = 0; i < RecentBaas.length; i++) { #
            # if (RecentBaas[i].Status == 1) { #
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <p>#=kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(RecentBaas[i].LastModDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd')#</p>
                </div>
            # } #
            # } #
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Let me know if its not working

Comment: Yep that worked! I didn't think I had to parse it first as I could have swore that I've done it before without parsing. Thanks though!